# How to compare two different dataframes in Pandas and set the corresponding values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two different size dataframes:

df1:

```py
         Name         All
   L_LV-SWB_1   10.300053
L_SWB_1-SWB_2    6.494196
L_SWB_2-SWB_3    4.738036
```

df2:

[image]

I want to create a new column in df2 called 'Isc' which contains the numerical values of df1, only if the 'On Element' column in df2 matches the 'Name' column in df1. Otherwise a 0 value is set.

Answer (score 0):

First, match the name of the column with the same value,

`df1.columns = ['On element','All']`

```
print(df1)

    On element      All
0   L_LV-SWB_1      10.300053
1   L_SWB_1-SWB_2   6.494196
2   L_SWB_2-SWB_3   4.738036
```

You just need to merge that value(On element) as a key.

`df = pd.merge(df2,df1,on='On element', how='left').fillna(0)`

```
print(df)
    Name    On element      All
0   CB_1-1  L_LV-SWB_1      10.300053
1   CB_1-2  L_SWB_1-SWB_2   6.494196
2   CB_2    L_LV-SWB_1      10.300053
3   CB_2-1  L_SWB_1-SWB_3   0
```